# need help developing a quiz app for android

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a quiz app for physics, but I keep getting the error

```
02-23 16:02:06.006: E/Database(9348): on sqlite3_open_v2("data/data/com.mcq.srm/databases/q.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
```

Code Snippet below

```
public class QuestionPane extends Activity {
    int counter  =00;
    RadioButton radioButton;
    TextView Question;
    TextView tvScore;
    Button Next;

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.questionpane);

        int resdb=0;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
             String DB_FULL_PATH = "data/data/com.mcq.srm/databases/q.db";
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_FULL_PATH, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
                checkDB.close();
                //Toast.makeText(this,"db  "+checkDB, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                resdb=0;
                Log.v("msg","Database created");

        } catch (Exception e){
            resdb=1;    
        }
        Log.v("msg", "check res-->"+resdb);
        try{
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("q.db" , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null );
            if(resdb==1)
            {
                Log.v("msg","creating tables");
                CreateTable();
                InsertData();   
                displayres();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

    public void CreateTable(){
        String Createtab;
          Createtab =" CREATE TABLE tbl_Question ("+ "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Questions TEXT, option_1 TEXT,option_2 TEXT, option_3 Text, option_4 TEXT, correct_answer TEXT);";
        try{
            db.execSQL(Createtab);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }   
  }
  public void InsertData(){
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("question", "Two beams of red and violet colours are made to pass separately through a prism of A = 60°. In the minimum deviation position, the angle of refraction inside the prism will be");
    //... value.put statements removed
       db.insert("tbl_Question", null, values);

       //.. values.put statements removed
       values.put("correct_answer","35 grams");
       db.insert("tbl_Question", null, values);
   }
   public void displayres() {
            int qno=1;

            String sql1="select * from  question;";

            Cursor c1=db.rawQuery(sql1,null);
            Log.v("answer","asd");
              String que,opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4;

              startManagingCursor(c1);
              c1.moveToFirst();
              que=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("Question1"));
              Log.v("answer",que);
        }
}
```

Comment: Try to provide a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example. Have a look at http://sscce.org/

Comment: Why the empty lines and the millions of `values.put` ? Next time please fix spelling mistakes, dont put millions of imports, //TODO's, empty lines and useless code repeats. Spare people the time to read your code and answer. And yeah, read the FAQ please.

Comment: did you check the actual time when the question was posted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of mistakes in your I'll suggest you go through [this](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842) example, it's best to start with that example in android.You need to create separate class for Database generally know as Database Adapter and one more that is Database Helper by Android Devs. So to get complete idea go through that example.

Comment: Thank you that was indeed helpful